# Are global variables always initialized with zeroes?

Tags: c, standards

Can I trust of this one:

> Section 6.7.8p10 Initialization of C standard

And will it always be set to 0? Are there exceptions to this rule (maybe compiler-specific ones)?

Comment: A global var is always set to null, unless you assign it another initial value.

Comment: If the C standard says global variables are set to zero then why shouldn't they be?

Comment: You are basically asking "if x says y, is x saying y?"...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I ask it because my teacher is get some bonuses from me because he try to prove that sometimes it's not set to zero. So I should get 12 point but receive 8 because he said that's its hard mistake even after pointing him to C standards. I clearly realize that's its some kind of magic. but to be sure I decide to ask.

Comment: @PetraGrygorenko Why don't you ask your teacher to provide an example where a global variable is not set to 0?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will and we end at local variable with garbage and phrase "So you see? this can happnes with global variable too" My teacher is old guy so maybe it's somehow related with age, maybe in his time there is such case exist. So I stop discussion this with him, because I understand that he not right.

Comment: Note that 6.7.8 §10 refers to an older C standard "C99". In the current standard C17 (and in C11), the correct chapter is 6.7.9 §10.

Comment: @PetraGrygorenko well such as case could exist on a _buggy_ C implementation. In a bugge environnment even declarations of global variables such as `int a = 0;` could go wrong.

Comment: @PetraGrygorenko I would guess that your teacher simply doesn't know the meaning of automatic/static storage duration or the difference between the two. Static storage duration variables (including globals) have always been guaranteed to be set to zero, since the first C standard in 1989. However, relying on this implicit zero initialization when writing code is not good practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if the compiler is a C compiler, all static variables that are not initialized otherwise will be initialized as if by `{ 0 }`. This means that floats and pointers will be as if initialized by `{ 0 }` even if the bit-pattern were different.

If the compiler has an option for it to become a not-C compiler then all bets are off.

Comment: Notably, almost every embedded systems compiler has such an option, in order to speed up system boot-up. But when such a "minimal startup" is enabled, those compilers no longer follow the standard.